# Impossible to choose any channel in Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

Since the new Azure Bot Service (released GA 2017-12-13), I've created a "WebAppBot" named "SanoBot" and I can't choose any channel to plug it for another services like Telegram: the page is empty when I click on "Channels". I've done a little screenshot to show you what I see:

[image: screenfromazure]

I've check the documentation sent by the Azure Support from Twitter but the pages return 404 error.

[image: 404 docs]

Just to be clear: the bot works well and I can modify it from the Online Editor, build, deploy & test it. It's only "channels" feature that doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

*I can't use pictures because I haven't enough reputation...*

Comment: can confirm that it's "overall" working so it's something specific to your issue. My first suggestion would be to contact Azure Support in the Azure portal. 
What link did the support team give you? I'd love to help diagnose.

Comment: Hello @JimLewallen, it's Azure Support who asks me to post my problem here and send them the link with `botframowork` tag :)

Comment: Yes, though over the last 24 hours we've now become the Azure Bot Service and they will be providing more support directly.

Maybe we'll get lucky here. What browser are you using?

Comment: @JérémieRabusseau Are you able to get to the channel configuration page at dev.botframework.com?  https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels?id=sanobot

Comment: There are two different Azure Support teams - Team A who got your report via Twitter and directed you here, and Team B who handles support requests initiated through the Azure management portal. You need to contact Team B via the Azure website.

Comment: @EricDahlvang no I can't since the new service because when I click on it, I'm redirect directly on my Azure account > Botframwork > MyBot.

For nilsw: Thanks, I'll check to be supported by Team B so !

Comment: @JérémieRabusseau Are you clicking on the bot in the list of My Bots?  Or, are you clicking this link directly: https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels?id=sanobot

Comment: @EricDahlvang Wow ! That works, you had hack the system only by using an URL ! Thanks, you resolve my problem.